# Crop and center an avatar in Codename One allowing the user to choose the region to crop

Tags: codenameone

About cropping and centering an avatar in **Codename One**, I saw similar examples in the manual, in the Javadoc and in the blog, for example the first block of code here:
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/capture/Capture.html

But I need something that is different and more difficult.

The main problem is that the face is not always in the exact center of the photo. Some apps allow the user to choose the region to crop.

For example, suppose that after capturing a photo it looks automatically cropped and centered so:

[image]

Of course it's wrong, I want the lion at the center. In this case, **it could be nice if the user can pinch-to-zoom the lion and drag it to the center of the cropping area**, getting something like this:

[image]

I don't know where to start to do this with Codename One. Is it possible to do it with a Form shown immediately after capturing a photo, that allows to pinch-to-zoom and center the photo in the cropping area like in the above image? Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: Of course the source of the photo is not restricted to the Camera, it can be also the Gallery or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial but we probably should have a standardized component that does that. Generally the best approach would be to have an `ImageViewer` as a layered layout component and an overlay mask on top. This is pretty easy to implement.

The hard part is cutting the image correctly based on the scale/pan values from the `ImageViewer` class.